# How to change the language in Magento after a server migration ?

Tags: php, magento, date, translation, locale

My Magento 1.6.2 is configured in French. Since I've moved my Magento installation, a module, using locale config variables to show day of week and month, is displaying days and months in English instead of French.

The module's developer says that it is retrieving the day and the month here :

```
<?php
class CJM_CustomStockStatus_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function getHolidays()
    {
        $holidays =     explode(',',Mage::getStoreConfig('custom_stock/shipoptions/holidays', Mage::app()-    >getStore()->getId()));
        $holidays = array_filter(array_map('trim', $holidays));
        $theDates =     explode(',',Mage::getStoreConfig('custom_stock/shipoptions/movingholidays', Mage::app()-    >getStore()->getId()));
        $theDates = array_filter(array_map('trim', $theDates));
        $year = date('o', Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time()));
        $allDates = array();
        $formattedDates = array();
        ...
```

I don't understand why this module is displaying the content in English since I've moved the server.

Comment: Maybe the server isn't set to the right locale.  use ` setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');` and see if that corrects the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was locale on server. Thank you !

Comment: good to hear.  I have transferred to an answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

use `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');` and see if that corrects the issue.